# Django Postgres DateRangeField - can I use UNIQUE vaildator

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use some of the shiny new Postgres fields in Django.

For a booking system the DateRangeField seems perfect.
Can I use the *validators UNIQUE* or even *UNIQUE_DATE* in regard to this field?

The excellent Django documentation is, unfortunately, not elaborating regarding validators and the Postgres fields.

Answer (score 2):

So basically, to my knowledge, the field option **unique** and **unique_for_date** do not work with Postgres DateRange fields.

However, there is a way using a Porstgres index
We need a **btree_gist** combined index in Postgres.
This is a Postgres extension and it is provided with Postgres, we just need to install it into the database with

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Once we have this, we can have a *constraint on the date_range field with combined with another field* in our table.

Say we have a hotel room number (room_id) and a booking date range (dt_range), which, combined, should be unique. Our constraint would be

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtablename> ADD EXCLUDE USING gist ( room_id WITH =, dt_range WITH && );
```

Now, whenever we have a booking for room room_id with conflicting booking dates, Postgres will throw an error which is a

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError
```

I hope that helps!